# Bash terminal lacking functionality when running as non-root

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, debian

I'm running a command-line Debian system, accessed via SSH through PuTTY, and am experiencing differing terminal functionality between root and other users.

When logging in as root, the terminal displays

```
root@mydomain:/currentdir
```

as I'd expect for a Debian system - I'm also able to use standard arrow key shortcuts (Up arrow key displays previous commands, etc.) However, when logged in as any other user, the terminal prompt simply shows `$`, and arrow keys register as `^[[A` (for Up) etc.

I'm curious to know what's causing this behavior, and how I can change it.

Comment: Have you compared `/home/root/.bashrc` and `/home/root/.bash_profile` to the corresponding files in `/home/other_user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not running `dash` as your default shell when you login as another user? On my computer it looks exactly like you describe:

```
self@debian~$ dash
$ ^[[A^[[A
```

It goes the same for `sh` (which actually seems to be an alias to dash) :

```
self@debian~$ sh
$ ^[[A^[[A
```

Comment: This was indeed the issue, thanks - running `echo $SHELL` as `otherUser` came up with `/bin/sh`. Changing this was simple - ran `chsh` and entered `bin/bash`. [This from here](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/change-shell-debian-linux/start)